# tox pytest import doesn't work in a subpackage

Tags: python, pytest, tox

I'm playing with this repo https://github.com/mCodingLLC/SlapThatLikeButton-TestingStarterProject. It shows automated testing in Python with pytest and tox.

After cloning the repo the following steps are performed:

- create a virtualenv
- `pip install -r requirements_dev.txt`
- `pip install -e .`
- `pytest` runs successfully
- `tox` runs successfully

I've made a slight change to the layout of `src` directory. Added a subpackage `src/models`, moved `slap_that_like_button.py` to this subpackage and updated tests accordingly. Now the tree and the test looks like this:

```
src
├── slapping
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── slap_that_like_button.py
    └── py.typed
```

```
diff --git a/tests/test_slapping.py b/tests/test_slapping.py
index 40ed2f4..8298ec5 100644
--- a/tests/test_slapping.py
+++ b/tests/test_slapping.py
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 import pytest
-from slapping.slap_that_like_button import LikeState, slap_many
+from slapping.models.slap_that_like_button import LikeState, slap_many


 def test_empty_slap():
```

Results:

- `pytest` runs successfully
- `tox` **fails** when runs `pytest` with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slapping.models'`. Full traceback https://gist.github.com/ttl256/1d77c1b62801e7b78fec6b116d307eb4

1. Why is it that `pytest` can successfully run from my terminal but can't find the subpackage when launched within `tox`?
2. How moving a module to a subpackage makes so much difference?

P.S. For anyone who wants play with the repo. Bump `tox` version in `requirements_dev.txt` to `4.11.4`. Otherwise it gives this traceback https://gist.github.com/ttl256/76499d8a3b1db0250d571a7fdd7d3b06

EDIT. Installing the package as editable solves the issue however root cause is still unknown.

```
$ git diff tox.ini
diff --git a/tox.ini b/tox.ini
index 6b58ff8..8730352 100644
--- a/tox.ini
+++ b/tox.ini
@@ -13,6 +13,7 @@ python =
 [testenv]
 setenv =
     PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}
+package = editable
 deps =
     -r{toxinidir}/requirements_dev.txt
 commands =
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `packages` definition in the option section of `setup.cfg`:

```
[options]
packages =
    slapping
install_requires =
    requests>=2
python_requires = >=3.6
package_dir =
    =src
zip_safe = no
```

When a new package was added `setuptools` didn't know about it. There are a couple of ways to signal `setuptools` about a new package and `find` works nicely here as it saves us from manually adding each package for this simple project.

```
diff --git a/setup.cfg b/setup.cfg
index 38c125f..095808a 100644
--- a/setup.cfg
+++ b/setup.cfg
@@ -14,15 +14,18 @@ classifiers =
     Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9

 [options]
-packages =
-    slapping
 install_requires =
     requests>=2
 python_requires = >=3.6
+packages = find:
 package_dir =
     =src
 zip_safe = no

+[options.packages.find]
+where = src
+exclude =
+
 [options.extras_require]
 testing =
     pytest>=6.0
```

Now as we add more packages `setuptools` will automatically discover them.

Reference on custom package discovery: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#custom-discovery